# How can I convert a CQL literal to a java object while writing custom codec for my UDT using datastax?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have a table in Cassandra keyspace called `User` which must have a UDT field called `Address`. The TYPE `Address` has been created and also the `User` table is created in the same keyspace. But while running the application it is asking for Codec for `Address.java` as following:

`Codec not found for requested operation: [UDT(library.address) <-> com.mypackage.demoapp.dao.Address]`.

So I am trying to now create a custom codec for my `Address.java` class. Following is the structure of the class:

```java
public class AddressCodec extends TypeCodec.AbstractUDTCodec<Address> {

    protected AddressCodec(UserType definition, Class<Address> javaClass) {
        super(definition, javaClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected Address newInstance() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected ByteBuffer serializeField(Address address, String s, ProtocolVersion protocolVersion) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Address deserializeAndSetField(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, Address address, String s, ProtocolVersion protocolVersion) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String formatField(Address address, String s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Address parseAndSetField(String input, Address address, String fieldName) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, I am not understanding how to map/serialize/de-serialize between the CQL fields and Java fields of `Address`. Some explanation or example code would be very helpful.

NOTE: I AM NOT USING SPRING FRAMEWORK, AND **NOT** LOOKING FOR ANY SPRING ORIENTED CONFIGURATION TECHNIQUES.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Java driver 3, instead of using `TypedCodec.AbstractUDTCodec` just follow the driver [documentation on codecs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.8/manual/custom_codecs/#creating-custom-codecs-for-user-defined-types-ud-ts), and implement your codec as following:

- Copy the whole source code of the `AddressCodec` in the documentation
- adjust `toAddress` and `toUDTValue` functions to get/set necessary fields of your POJO

For Java driver 4.x, with Object Mapper, just annotate your POJO with `@Entity` (add `@CqlName` if necessary, when of POJO is different than name of UDT).  See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.7/manual/mapper/entities/) on it.

Comment: This really helped in giving an idea how to write the Codec, however even after doing the following:

AddressCodec addressCodec = new AddressCodec(addressTypeCodec, Address.class);
codecRegistry.register(addressCodec);


It is not registering the codec. What could I be missing?

Comment: how do you access data?

Comment: I have an entity called User within which Address is used. Now to access user, I have UserDAO interface annotated with `@Dao`  and the method `@Select User findById(UUID id);` is used for querying by ID and `@Insert void save(User user)` is used to save the entity. Using a mapper obtained from DAOMapperBuilder I obtain a reference to UserDAO and then use the above mentioned methods.

Comment: ah, you're using Java Driver 4 - just mark your class as `@Entity`, and it will generate codec automatically. I've updated the answer

Comment: Yes, you're right, I am using java-driver 4.x. However, marking `@Entity` is not doing anything different. My `User` POJO was already marked with `@Entity` and my `Address` POJO was already marked with `@UDT`. So I tried replacing `@UDT` with `@Entity` but didn't help.

Comment: Following is the Address POJO definition: https://pastebin.com/y12MAX6W
And following is the User POJO definition: https://pastebin.com/mMMVfKVB

Comment: And here you will find how I am trying to read/write User and Address: https://pastebin.com/yDyn4myt

Comment: it could be that you're not using it correctly - please refer to the driver documentation for full example.  With object mapper you don't need to register codecs manually - everything is done by object mapper for you. You just need to configure Maven correctly to generate & compile boilerplate code, and then include runtime dependencies

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. I removed `@Udt` and replaced it with `@Entity` on `Address` and also removed the code which was trying to explicitly register the codec.

Comment: is there a way to have tables generated from the annotated Entities and UDTs?

Comment: No, it's deliberate choice of developers of not doing this in runtime, as it could be dangerous - you can easy get schema disagreement

Comment: So, like SpringBoot provides auto generation of tables from entities, is there anything other than spring that I could use with datastax to auto generate tables from entities?